# Create List [x-n, x-n+1,...,x,x+1,x+2,...x+n] in Java

Tags: java, implementation

I'd like to get a method returning ArrayList as following:

```
int x = ...;
int n = ...;
List<Integer> list = getList(x,n);
System.out.println(list.size()) // => 2n+1
int i = ...;
for(int elem : list){
  System.out.println(elem);
} // => x-n, x-n+1, x-n+2,..., x-1, x, x+1,..., x+n
```

For instance,

```
getList(3,1) // => [2,3,4]
getList(5,3) // => [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

What is the efficient implementation of `getList()`?

Comment: You description about 'efficient' is not clear. Do you mean the most simple implementation? Or the implementation which is most fast and has most small memory usage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is the code basically use for loop, its initial value x-n and it will loop up to x+n

```
    public List<Integer> getList(int x,int n){
        int lower = x-n ; 
        int upper = x + n ; 
        List<Integer> ls= new ArrayList<Integer>() ; 
        for(int i = lower ; i<=upper ; i++){
            ls.add(i) ; 
        }

   return ls ; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code basically loops the array once. In order to let your code be robust, you must consider cases where n is zero or negative.

```
public List<Integer> getList(int x, int n) {
    ArrayList<Integer> returnVal = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    if (n < 0) {
        for (int i = n; i <= -n; i++) {
             returnVal.add(i + x);
        }
    }
    else {
        for (int i = -n; i <= n; i++) {
             returnVal.add(i + x);
        }
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```